Graph hits in Kibana from a complex ElasticSearch query
I have a complex ES query which runs as expected in the Dev Tool, and I want to graph the number of hits returned by this query, per day (day is a date field in the document).
The actual query shouldn't matter, I'd need this for multiple different queries, but I can't find how to graph the number of hits per day for the query.
The document structure is:
{
  "id": "blah-223",
  "date": "2024-01-12",
  "data": "Some big text that gets queried with phrase search",
  "tags": ["some", "tags", "that", "also", "get", "queried"]
}

What I'd like to get is a graph where the X axis shows dates, and the Y axis shows the number of hits from a query for that particular date.

Use Kibana's visualization tools to create a Date Histogram on the 'date' field, apply your complex query as a filter, and set the Y-axis to display the count of documents to graph the number of hits per day.
